# Empirical vs Analytical?

Tags: numerical-methods, machine-learning, empirical-processes

I have been reading some literature on Machine Learning and whenever I try to brush up my mathematical concepts, I come across an avid use of the terms empirical (ex. we can 'empirically' prove it, 'empirical' distribution)

and the term analytical (ex: the concept of matrix inversion helps us 'analytically' solve the eqn : Ax = b)

I see that they are used in complimentary scenarios but I am not able to find any concrete definitions of these terms in the mathematical sense. 
Can someone help clarify the differences between these?

Comment: Empirical means obtained from data and observations. Analytical means derived purely through mathematical reasoning.

Comment: There's a whole area called Experimental Mathematics. While experiments conducted in mathematics or computer science are different than the ones in physics or chemistry, they are still a valid method of research

Answer (score 1):

From dictionary meanings:

empirical: based on, concerned with, or verified by observation or experience.

analytical: based on analysis or logic.

Besides this, there are technical terms.

The empirical distribution for a random variable based on a finite set of observations gives each observed value the probability consisting of the fraction of observations that have that value.

An analytical expression is a formula that can be written down using the basic arithmetic operations (+-*/^) and "well-known" functions.  Not to be confused with [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function).